# Cloud Dataflow Streaming continuously failing to insert

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My dataflow pipeline functions as so:

```
Read from Pubsub
Transform data into rows
Write the rows to bigquery
```

On, occasion data is passed which fails to insert. That is alright, I know the reason for this failure. But dataflow continuously attempts to insert this data over and over and over and over. I would like to limit the number of retries as it bloats the worker logs with irrelevant information. Therefore making it extremely difficult to troubleshoot what is the problem when the same error repeatedly appears.

When running the pipeline locally I get:

```
no evaluator registered for Read(PubsubSource)
```

I would love to be able to test the pipeline locally. But it does not seem that dataflow supports this option with PubSub.

To clear the errors I am left with no other choice than canceling the pipeline and running a new job on the Google Cloud. Which costs time & money. Is there a way to limit the errors? Is there a way to test my pipeline locally? Is there a better approach to debugging the pipeline?

[Dataflow UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8T1E.png)

Job ID: 2017-02-08_09_18_15-3168619427405502955

Comment: There is currently no way to limit errors besides exception handling. See The note at the bottom here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/troubleshooting-your-pipeline#detecting-an-exception-in-worker-code  It will indefinitely try to rerun your code. I don't think there's a way to test with Pub/Sub locally, if you look at the examples they usually read from a CSV file for data on a local run.

Comment: Hypothetically, is it possible to have Dataflow acknowledge a Pubsub message when an exception arises? From what I can tell unless the Pubsub message is successfully processed Cloud Dataflow will never acknowledge the message.

Comment: That is probably entirely up to what kind of exceptions you are expecting and want to handle. As an example, you can take a look at this blog post https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow  In my case I am receiving and parsing JSON messages from Pub/Sub, and if that conversion fails I catch and log the payload for later analysis.

Comment: I'm taking a look at your job. I'll report back in a few hours.

Comment: As a note, you should be able to read from PubSub with the DirectRunner. If you post your code, we may be able to debug that and help you test it locally.

Comment: Have you verified your table schema for inserting into bigquery? Or if you have a query being executed, you may also try it in your bigquery console to verify that it works.

Comment: @IdreesKhan Thanks for the reply. That code snippet is extremely useful. Are there more blogs that regularly post Dataflow examples and topics?`-`
Running the pipeline locally, I get variance in errors
`no evaluator registered for Read(PubsubSource)`
Occurs when the program manages to create a topic subscription. When googling the issue responses indicate that pubsub does not work loccally.
`Unable to get application default credentials`
This occurs on occasion when it can't read my credentials JSON file. The JSON file exists and contains my credentials. This error isnt easily reproduced.

Comment: @Pablo the pipeline works with my table schema. I am looking for ways of optimizing my workflow. If I could run my pipeline locally that would really help me. The Dataflow documentation on error handling is a bit weak. Are there any other useful dataflow resources?

Comment: Are you trying to run the job locally using the `DirectPipelineRunner`? Try running your pipeline locally using `InProcessPipelineRunner`, which should support streaming.

Comment: Thanks so much! The `InProcessPipelineRunner` has allowed me to test my program much more effectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the pipeline locally with unbounded data sets, on @Pablo's suggestion use the `InProcessPipelineRunner`.

```
        dataflowOptions.setRunner(InProcessPipelineRunner.class);
```

Running the program locally has allowed me to handle errors with exceptions and optimize my workflow rapidly.